# How do I get a random number to stay fixed with slick?

Tags: random, slick2d

I'm a beginner in Java as well as with the slick tools. I want to make a game that has different coloured cubes randomly placed within a certain area of the window.

I use two for-loops and call for a random number in render. I get the cubes placed exactly as I want, but the problems is that they flicker in all colours. I guess it has to do with how I call for a random number and that it gets updated with FPS?!

Please help me!!

```
    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sdg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    //set background

    Image background = (new Image("res/background.png")).getScaledCopy(800, 500);   
    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0);

    //set gamescape
    blue = (new Image("res/blue.png")).getScaledCopy(20,20);
    green = (new Image("res/green.png")).getScaledCopy(20,20);
    red = (new Image("res/red.png")).getScaledCopy(20,20);
    int xvalue = 300;
    int yvalue = 400;


    for (int a = 1; a < 20; a++) {

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {  
            r = rand.nextInt(3);
            if(r==0){g.drawImage(blue,xvalue,yvalue);}

            else if(r==1){g.drawImage(red, xvalue, yvalue);}

            else{g.drawImage(green, xvalue, yvalue);}

            xvalue = xvalue+20;
        }
        yvalue = yvalue - 20;
        xvalue = xvalue -180;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you generate a new random number each time you redraw the scene.

To resolve this, you may have to create an array in which you store the generated color of each cube. And each time you redraw your images, you just read each color value in the array.